# Mysql get records for each customer by day

Tags: mysql

I would like to get total number of orders for each customer and product name  daily for the last 7 days.

This is what I have now but it gives orders for each day also I want to group it under unique customers. Please see screenshot for clarification. Is there a way to do this in one mysql query? Thanks in advance for your replies.[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtN9w.jpg)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`Order_ID`) AS Order_ID,
    `Status`,
    Customer_Name,
    Product_Name,
    `Order_Date`
FROM `customers`
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = customers.order_id
GROUP BY DATE(`Order_Date`), Customer_Name
ORDER BY `orders`.`Order_Date` DESC
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtN9w.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your `customers` and `order` tables DDL?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Please add your current result and expected result of the `SQL`

Comment: "Please see screenshot for clarification." What screen shot? Also, why are you grouping by agent?

Comment: fixed it now it seems better

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you gotta do it in two step but if you have order quantity, i'd replace Count(order_id) by count(quantity) as total_quantity.

```
SELECT
Customer_Name, COUNT(Order_ID) as Order_ID
FROM
customers
LEFT JOIN
orders
ON
orders.order_id=customers.order_id 
GROUP BY
Customer_Name
```

and

```
SELECT
Product_Name, COUNT(Order_ID) as Order_ID
FROM
customers
LEFT JOIN
orders
ON
orders.order_id=customers.order_id 
GROUP BY
Product_Name
```